# Redirecting Anonymous Users to external URL on Drupal 8 site

Tags: 8, users, redirection, event-subscribers

I am attempting to create a custom module that redirects anonymous/unauthenticated users away from the site. This site is only supposed to be used by admins, so in order to access it, they must type `/user/login` at the end of the url to be taken to a log in page.

I have my `mymodule.info.yml` file created as well as my `mymodule.module` file.

Then in `mymodule.services.yml` file I have:

```
services:
  redirect_unauthenticated_user.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\redirect_unauthenticated_user\EventSubscriber\RedirectAnonymousSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

In my `/src/EventSubscriber` folder I have a `RedirectAnonymousSubscriber.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hid_redirect_unauthenticated_user\EventSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;


/**
 * Event subscriber subscribing to KernelEvents::REQUEST.
 */
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public function checkAuthStatus() {

    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous() && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() !== 'user/login') {

      $response = new RedirectResponse('google.com', 301);
      $response->send();
      return;
    }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkAuthStatus');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Here, I am trying to check if the user is anonymous/unauthenticated and are not on the user/login page, redirect them to an external url (google.com for example here).

Finally, I have a `mymodule.routing.yml` file (which I'm not even sure if I need):

```
hid_redirect_unauthenticated_user.content:
  path: '/hid_redirect_unauthenticated_user'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\hid_redirect_unauthenticated_user\EventSubscriber\RedirectAnonymousSubscriber::getSubscribedEvents'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Currently my site redirects even when I type /user/login at the end of my url. I apologize if this is all over the place but I've been playing with it for a while and feel like I'm confusing myself. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, and I might not help the OP, but I will leave a solution here for future reference.

The status code needs to be [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) instead of [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) since 301 is meant for permanent redirects which will cause bugs on your site. (meaning no matter what conditions and "if statements" you have, it will redirect. Even if you are logged in). You can read more about [HTTP status codes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

So you change this code: `$response = new RedirectResponse('google.com', 301);`

to this: `$response = new RedirectResponse('google.com', 302);`
and everything should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Your route name is incorrect. You are making a comparison of the path, rather than the route name:

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() !== 'user/login'
```

The route name of the user login page is user.login, so you should use that:

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() !== 'user.login'
```

Comment: I had it like that before and didn't change anything. Thanks though!

Comment: You need to clear the registry after making any changes like this, as responses will be cached. You may need to clear your browser cache as well, as browsers sometimes cache redirects.

Comment: Clear the registry? Is that a Drupal thing or could you point me where to find it? I've never heard of it.

Comment: It’s a Drupal thing. Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance.

Comment: For some reason I messed up my redirection so bad I can even get onto my Drupal site.. it redirects me even when I type in /user/login. Is there a command line way to clear the registry?

Comment: You can use Drush to clear the registry. That’s what I recommend.

Comment: You can also truncate (not delete) all the database tables that begin with `cache_`, however this can be dangerous if you accidentally truncate the wrong table. Drush is better.

Comment: I found this https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild but it seems that applies only for Drupal 7, I couldn't find anything for clearing the registry via Drush for a Drupal 8 site. I appreciate your help

Comment: You just run `drush cr`. It's part of Drush core. You only need to install Drush.

Comment: Oh I've ran that many times.. no luck. It's weird because I removed the code that redirected the site to an external URL and replaced it to redirect to '/user/login' but it still redirects to that external URL so I'm really confused about that.

Comment: In that case it's probably your browser cache. Clear that.